# Does soulbinding have any effect on items?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

In Final Fantasy XIV is soulbinding only a prerequisite to using an item to create materia, or does it have some other effect on the item?

Answer (score 2):

It has no other effect on the item except binding the item to you so you can't trade it to another player or sell it on the Marketboard.